# Django - Using the object list in the admin panel somewhere else

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I achieved to list objects of my model class at "/admin/app1/influencer/" and i can sort objects by fields, add new objects, update and delete existing objects; that's cool for me as i'm new to Django.

What i want to accomplish is make a page that doesn't require admin privileges (no CRUD operations except adding a new object) and lists the objects, sorts them, filters them etc. That page only should require normal user login. In order to do that i created a class view:

```
class InfluencerList(ListView):
    model = Influencer
```

Added this line to my apps url.py:

```
path('influencers/', InfluencerList.as_view()),
```

Then i created an html file in my apps templates folder and listed all the objects in table rows with that:

```
{% for influencer in object_list %}
```

I'm not sure that this is the best way to do that. That stuff must be already written somewhere in Django and it will take some time for me to add searching, sorting, filtering. I searched on the web that stuff but only found what i have already done (just listing some data in rows). What approach should i use in this kind of situation? Thanks for any advice and help.

Comment: The _already written_ stuff you are looking for is `CreateView` with `LoginRequiredMixin`.

Comment: Look at https://djangopackages.org. You might find a 3rd party package that can help you start your project. But within Django itself, there isn't a ready-made list view with sorting, searching and filtering outside of the admin site.